# Multiplying each value with every other value in a vector

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have a vector like:

```
ar=[0,1,2,3]
```

I want to multiply every value with eachother. And my output could be like:

```
ar2=[[0,0,0],
     [0,2,3],
     [0,2,6],
     [0,3,6]]
```

Could you help me for creating a "for loop"?

Comment: Arrays? Numpy?.

Comment: yes it is an array.

Comment: But is it a numpy array?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you were *supposed* to finish before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If you don't know what [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) is, and you're trying to do stuff with arrays, you should definitely go learn. In NumPy, to multiply two arrays, you just do `x * y`. Of course the arrays do have to be an appropriate shape, so, there are things to learn with NumPy, just like there are things to learn with for loops. But once you learn it, it's amazingly helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this using list concatenation

```
res = [[i*j for j in a if i!=j] for i in a]

[[0, 0, 0], 
[0, 2, 3], 
[0, 2, 6], 
[0, 3, 6]]
```

Edit:
Explanation: This runs two loops and multiplies `i` and `j` if the values are not equal.
As @abarnert pointed out, this will not work if the values are repeated, something like `[1, 0, 2, 2]`

In that case, we can use the index to identify the element instead of values.

Edit2: As pointed out by @coldspeed, using `enumerate` is a cleaner and better way to do this, e.g.:

```
res =[[x * y for i, y in enumerate(a) if i != j] for j, x in enumerate(a)]
```

Using `range`, we can do this way:

```
res = [[a[i]*a[j] for j in range(0,len(a)) if i!=j] for i in range(0,len(a))]
```

Running this for `a = [0 ,1 ,2 ,2]` we get

```
[[0, 0, 0],
 [0, 2, 2], 
 [0, 2, 4], 
 [0, 2, 4]]
```

Comment: This only works if all of the values are unique. Or maybe the OP wants to multiple each value by each value that's not equal, rather than each value other than itself; it's not entirely clear. But even if you think that's what he wants, I think you should explain that.

Comment: Great, you've superceded my edit. The change is this: `[[x * y for i, y in enumerate(ar) if i != j] for j, x in enumerate(ar)]
`

Comment: @abarnert very well, thanks a lot for pointing that out. I've edited it.

Comment: @coldspeed sorry, didn't realize that. On a side note, what in your opinion is a better way, `enumerate` or `range` ?

Comment: Enumerate, it's just cleaner, and gives you both the index and the value at the same time without all the extra indexing.

Comment: Agreed that `enumerate` is better. But either way, I don't think giving the OP a dense multiline nested comprehension is that helpful when he's having trouble writing basic `for` statements.

Answer (score 2):

> Could you help me for creating a "for loop"?

The for loop is the easy part. Although it's actually *two* for loops, nested, because you need "every" value with "each" other. So:

```
for every_value in ar:
    for each_other in ar:
```

The tricky part is that you want to multiply by each *other* value—that is, every value except itself.

It's not entirely clear whether you mean you want each value to skip multiplying by equal values, or you only want to skip multiplying by itself. Of course there is no difference with `[0,1,2,3]` because there are no equal values, but if you try it with, say, `[0,1,2,0]`, do you want to get 3 values in every row, or 3 values in some rows and 2 in others?

I'll assume you want to just skip the value itself. While there are cleverer ways to do this, let's pick the simpler one: use the index.

```
for i, x in enumerate(ar):
    for j, y in enumerate(ar):
        if i == j:
            continue # don't multiply a value by itself
```

So now, it's just a matter of multiplying and storing the values:

```
ar2 = []
for i, x in enumerate(ar):
    row = []
    for j, y in enumerate(ar):
        if i == j:
            continue
        row.append(x * y)
    ar2.append(row)
```

If you want to make this more compact, you can turn the inner loop into a comprehension:

```
ar2 = []
for i, x in enumerate(ar):
    row = [x * y for j, y in enumerate(ar) if i != j]
    ar2.append(row)
```

Or even the whole thing:

```
ar2 = [[x * y for j, y in enumerate(ar) if i != j]
       for i, x in enumerate(ar)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
ar=[0,1,2,3]
expected_list=[]

for i in range(len(ar)):
    temp_list = []
    for j in range(len(ar)):
        if i!=j:
            temp_list.append(ar[i]*ar[j])
    expected_list.append(temp_list)
print(expected_list)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 2, 3], [0, 2, 6], [0, 3, 6]]
```